# How to restore SharePoint from SQL backups?

Tags: backup, restore, sql, server

I have been tasked with restoring our SharePoint instance for our Disaster Recovery Procedure. We store our backups of SharePoint onto tape via Netvault, we use the SQL plugin and also backup the entire system. So my understanding so far is that I need to backup the unattached content database then import it again into SharePoint. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602%28v=office.15%29.aspx Unfortunately when attempting backup the unattached database I receive this error 'SharePoint object [SPContentDatabase Name=restored_content] is in an unsupported state, and could not be used by the current farm. '. Any help with getting round this would be great. Also if there is an easier method of restoring SharePoint from the data I have I would be more than welcome to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.

I managed to sort this yesterday. I had to edit the versions of the database due to a Schema mismatch error. After that I was able to create a new Site Collection and add the restored database as the Content Database for that site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the native backup/restore features in SharePoint have never been the most robust.  SharePoint 2013 is much better but still not 100% perfect. From your question, I am not sure if you are trying to "backup" a site collection from an unattached DB and restore or simply backup the DB itself.  For the process you linked, you are only backing up a site collection from that unattached DB and restoring it to a DB that is attached to SharePoint already.  If you need the DB, that can be obtained from a native SQL backup. If the backup SPsite part is not working with that error, my best guess is that the backup you are working with was taken a while ago and the version may be different.  As a test, you could create a new web application and try attaching the DB to it in order to see if that is successful.  If you are looking for an easier way to backup/restore, there are third party options, but it all depends on what you need.